# How to disable input type text, if value=true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to disable input type when the value of the input is true

```
("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE id='studid'")     

<input type='text' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['studid']; ?>' />
```

How can I do that ? Help me :(

Comment: I don't really understand "when the value of the input is true"

Comment: So if "studid" is not null you want to disable the input?

Comment: you mean `disabled` **if** (if what) ?

Comment: I mean if studid = not null , the input type must be disable @OldPadawan

Comment: `if studid = not null` means `studid has a value` -> but it must have a value, according to your query, otherwise, your query would return = 0 so no need for any input. Do I miss something here ? Or do you mean `if my query returns rows, then disable input, if no result, then regular input`?

Comment: if studid = not null means studid has a value, yes this what im saying, sorry for my mistaken grammar, Im a pure filipino

Comment: Im so sorry padawan, but I cant understand some english hope you understand me, but I will make it understandable,

Comment: What I mean is , If the studid = not null then the input type will be disabled, and if the input type = null the input type must be not disabled , @OldPadawan

Comment: don't worry about your english, we all (non-english native speakers) do our best to understand each other ;)

Comment: Thanks :) , Will you help me ? :) @OldPadawan

Comment: weel, the best I can do, if answers from the others don't match your needs is : `run your query -> count num_rows -> if results == 1 -> <input type="text" name="id" value="$studid" disabled="disabled" /> else <input type="text" name="id" value="whatever_you_want_to_put_in_it" />` but it's kind of same solution...

Comment: I will try this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Echo it out as php, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by if stuid is true..? If it isn't true it doesn't exist and if it doesn't exist it shouldn't be the value of your input ....

```
if($row['studid'] == ""){
   echo "<input type='text' name='id' value='' disabled/>";
}else{
   echo "<input type='text' name='id' value='' />";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really disable it. It just doesn't create it. Not really what the OP asked.

Comment: I want to disable the iput type so the user cant type on it when there is a value, but thanks for this :)

Comment: that does that. It disables (attrib disabled), if you don't have a studid, otherwise it prints it with the ability to type (no attribute disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
if(isset($row['studid']))
{
$dis='disabled';
}
else
{
$dis='';
}
<input type='text' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['studid']; ?>' <?=$dis?> />
```